# load a csv file successfully, but nodes showing no properties

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I loaded a csv file of 200 rows. The csv file has actor_id,first name, last name, last update attributes.

When I entered:

*LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/CSV/actor.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Actor {actor_id: row.actor_id, first_name: row.first_name, last_name: row.last_name, last_update: row.last_update});*

It showed : "Added 199 labels, created 199 nodes returned 0 rows in 400 ms"

However properties which should contain actor_id, first name, last name, last update is empty

Comment: are you sure the header names are right? case sensitive!

Comment: I'm a beginner and I dont know what are header names. Please ellaborate

Comment: you're loading a CSV "with headers"--this means the first row is treated as header names so you can refer to them as a map called row. If those headers aren't there, then you'll get nulls for row.last_name, etc.--and nulls can't be property values (so they just won't get added if they don't match)

Comment: Perhaps you can share the first 10 rows of your CSV file